# Classes generated by XML Data Generator Tool are not contained within the specified namespace

Tags: namespaces, xsd, c++-cli, xsd.exe

I have the same problem as described in this connect issue

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/577382/classes-generated-by-xml-data-generator-tool-are-not-contained-within-the-specified-namespace

"An XSD file using the XML Data Generator Tool within a C++/CLI project will create a set of classes that are NOT within a namespace. The classes should be within the namespace specified by the Namespace property of the XML Data Generator Tool. This was detected when upgrading a VS2008 project to VS2010."

I see the /namespace option is on the command line of the XML Data Generator tool but still it does not write the namespace.

In VS 2008

```
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=2.0.50727.3038.
// 
namespace IOLib {
    using namespace System;
    ref class CPDS;
```

In VS 2010

```
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.1.
// 
using namespace System;
ref class CPDS;
```

Is there a way to force xsd tool to write the namespace too.

Answer (score 1):

for `xsd.exe` the parameter `/n:` is used to specify the namespace. Don't put a space between the parameter and the value.

Example:

`xsd myschema.xsd /c /n:MyNamespace`

Comment: the syntax /n was enough for me to add the namespace. No need for : in my case

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio uses MSBuild to build the targets specified in the solution.  They seem to be abandoning C++ in favor of VB and C#.  VS 2010 uses settings in

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets`
```

file.  The XSD section is missing an entry namely "Namespace". I set mine to

```
Namespace ="%(Xsd.Namespace)"
```

and compliled the xsd and the classes are now in the namespace I specify in the projects property pages.